# C binary file not working properly

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem.It is a homework and don't understandig it.This simple program asks the user to write into a file his/her name and telephone number and if it finds RDS phone number ex(`0*3*12415324`) then writes out to a binary file its owner and phone number.
The problem is that the program doesn't writes nothing into binary file(output.dat).

So far I done this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    char tel[50];

} PERSON;



int main()
{
    FILE *fin,*fout;
    int n, i;
    PERSON p[50];
    fin = fopen("input.txt","rt");
    fout = fopen("output.dat","wb");
    fscanf(fin,"%i", &n);
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        fscanf (fin,"%s%s", p[i].name, p[i].tel);
    }
    for (i=0; i<n; ++i){
        if (p[i].tel[1]=='3'){
            fwrite(p[i].name,sizeof(PERSON),n,fout);
            fwrite(p[i].tel,sizeof(PERSON),n,fout);
        }
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you *must* check the return values from all system calls. (like fopen, fwrite,...)

Comment: But it is a txt file where every name and telephone number is located.Only those names and numbers go in the binary file which are RDS numbers.

Comment: Use your debugger or put some `printf`s at strategic places in your code so see what's going on.

Comment: BTW: your program as it stands here doesn't ask anything from the user.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As a side note, your second and third parameter for `fwrite` make no sense; `p[i].name` and `p[i].tel` are arrays of 50 characters, _not_ arrays of `n` times `PERSON`.

Comment: @Alter Mann C does not defined `"rt"` to be invalid, rather it is undefined.  On OP's platform `"rt"` may well be defined.

Comment: @chux, oops you are right, I didn't know that: `If the string begins with one of the above sequences, the implementation might choose to ignore the remaining characters, or it might use them to select different kinds of a file (some of which might not conform to the properties in 7.19.2).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code I get a segfault.  Running [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) reveals the problem.

```
==75112== Invalid read of size 8
==75112==    at 0x1001D0C5F: flockfile (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==75112==    by 0x1001D303C: fscanf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==75112==    by 0x100000D42: main (test.c:21)
==75112==  Address 0x68 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==75112== 
==75112== 
==75112== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==75112==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x68
==75112==    at 0x1001D0C5F: flockfile (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==75112==    by 0x1001D303C: fscanf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==75112==    by 0x100000D42: main (test.c:21)
```

`fscanf` was passed a bogus filehandle because the `fopen` failed. In this case I didn't have an `input.txt`.  Always check the result of `fopen`.  I use a wrapper function to ensure this always happens.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *open_file(const char *filename, const char *mode) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, mode);
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s: %s.\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(errno);
    }

    return fp;
}
```

When I replace `fopen` with `open_file` I get a nice error message.

```
$ ./test
Could not open input.txt: No such file or directory.
```

---

Ok, `touch input.txt` and run again.  Another segfault.  Valgrind again...

```
==75478== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==75478==    at 0x100000D0F: main (test.c:32)
==75478== 
==75478== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==75478==    at 0x100000D91: main (test.c:36)
==75478== 
==75478== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==75478==    at 0x100000DB9: main (test.c:37)
```

The first two are about `n`, its uninitialized because input.txt is empty. The `fscanf` which was supposed to populate it fails, so `n` contains whatever garbage it started with.  The loop runs a random number of times based on the garbage in `n`.  It tries, and fails, to read from input.txt so `p` is left uninitialized and also containing garbage.

The 3rd error is about trying to read that trash in `p`.  `n` contains garbage so the for loop runs trying to read from the uninitialized `p` array.

This can all be fixed by initializing `n` and, as before, checking that `fscanf` worked.  Again, a wrapper function ensures the error is checked for.

```
int scan_check(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int ret = vfscanf(stream, format, args);

    if( ret <= 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not match input to '%s'.\n", format);
        exit(errno);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

---

Now it runs to the end.  All good, right?  Nope, `valgrind` speaks again.

```
==76285== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==76285==    at 0x1002DE97A: write$NOCANCEL (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==76285==    by 0x1001D8844: _swrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==76285==    by 0x1001D12FE: __sflush (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==76285==    by 0x1001D1001: fclose (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==76285==    by 0x100000E6E: main (test.c:60)
==76285==  Address 0x100806bc4 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 4,096 alloc'd
==76285==    at 0x100008EBB: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:303)
==76285==    by 0x1001D468E: __smakebuf (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==76285==    by 0x1001E91DF: __swsetup (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==76285==    by 0x1001D3928: __sfvwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==76285==    by 0x1001D3F02: fwrite (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==76285==    by 0x100000DDB: main (test.c:54)
```

This is telling us there's something wrong with the `fwrite` calls.

```
fwrite(p[i].name,sizeof(PERSON),n,fout);
fwrite(p[i].tel,sizeof(PERSON),n,fout);
```

This says to write `n` items each the size of a `PERSON` struct.  This would be fine if you were writing all of `p`.  But you're writing just one name and one telephone number.  Instead you want to write characters equal to the length of the string, plus one for the null byte.

```
fwrite(p[i].name, sizeof(char), strlen(p[i].name)+1, fout);
fwrite(p[i].tel,  sizeof(char), strlen(p[i].tel)+1 , fout);
```

---

Finally, putting it all together, valgrind has no complaints.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    PERSON p[50];

    FILE *fin = open_file("input.txt","rt");
    FILE *fout = open_file("output.dat","wb");

    scan_check(fin,"%i", &n);

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        scan_check(fin,"%s%s", p[i].name, p[i].tel);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i){
        if (p[i].tel[1]=='3'){
            fwrite(p[i].name, sizeof(char), strlen(p[i].name)+1, fout);
            fwrite(p[i].tel,  sizeof(char), strlen(p[i].tel)+1 , fout);
        }
    }

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```

---

This code can be made even more safe by eliminating the fixed size `p` array.  It's not necessary.  Instead of storing a list of people to output later, a list which will overflow if there's more than 50 people in `input.txt`, output them as you see them in a single for loop.

```
PERSON p;

....

for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
    scan_check(fin,"%s%s", p.name, p.tel);

    if (p.tel[1]=='3'){
        fwrite(p.name, sizeof(char), strlen(p.name)+1, fout);
        fwrite(p.tel,  sizeof(char), strlen(p.tel)+1 , fout);
    }
}
```

`n` is similarly unnecessary. There's no need for `input.txt` to tell you how many records there are, instead read the file until `eof(fin)`. This avoids `n` being inaccurate.

Comment: C:\Users\zsombi\Desktop\Egyetem\Programozas II\Labor 3\RDSbinarisan\main.c|42|error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'stream'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 4 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

I know about this error but it doesn't needed to be changed.

Comment: @Zsombi Sorry, I don't know what your line 42 is, but I think I know what happened. I left some includes out deliberately so you can't just cut & paste. :)